# Very new to HTML/JavaScript, how do I use onclick to change background color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When the page loads I want the page to be black and when you click it should change to white. I have the Javascript code to change it to white but I'm not sure how to change it to white only when you click.

```
#divMain {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:320px;
height:460px;
background-color:black;
```

Here I need to change background-color to white on click.

```
function body_load() {
document.getElementById('divMain').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";}
```

Here is the Javascript function I use to change the background to white. How can I only have it change to white when I click?

Also, when the page loads the function body_load() is ran.

Answer (score 0):

well add to the body tag:

```
<body onclick="body_load()">
```

if you want only divMain clickable:

```
var body_load = function() {
    document.getElementById('divMain').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
}
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('divMain').onclick = body_onload;
}
```